# DeepLinks and proper way to deal with page non fount

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to implement uni_link in a flutter app.
I set manifest.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data
  android:scheme="https"
  android:pathPrefix="/unilink/"
  android:host="[Url.it]" />
</intent-filter>
```

I added the assetlinks.json file in the .well-know folder

```
[   {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "[package_name]",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints":[sha256]
    }   } ]
```

also running the command:

```
  adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW \
     -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE \
     -d "http://www.[Url.it]/unilink/?id=10"
```

My web site opens with the message 404 page not found

some advice?